# Scaling up a Azure WebApp from S3 to Premium V2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've read that the Premium plan includes SSD disks for improved performance.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Does anyone know if i'm currently on the S3 Plan (using traditional HDD) and scale up to  P2V2 will my app automatically get deployed to the SSD?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Premium v1 (using A series machines), the upgrade to Premium v2 does not happen automatically. You'll need to go to the "scale up" option in your App Service Plan and select Pv2 by the size you need (1, 2 or 3).

Comment: Do you know if upgrading from Standard Plan to Premium V2 will swap the disk from HDD to SSD?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't. See the details here for the Dv2 series VMs used in the Premium v2 app service plans:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general#dv2-series